# Load balancing and virtual host 

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, virtualhost, bandwidth-control

I am using Apache2 .
Serving image and code on the same server.
I want to make image serving on different virtual host like "img.domain.com" and code on main host "domain.com" .

And question is if i can limit the bandwidth of image serving virtual host , because if virtual host goes out of bandwidth it will not effect the main host.

I am very new in server management thing (more a programmer).

I hope the above makes sense :P .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check "mod_bandwidth" for apache.

download link, 
http://www.cohprog.com/v3/bandwidth/download-en.html

here is documentation. 
http://www.cohprog.com/v3/bandwidth/doc-en.html

i've never used this module, 
so if you consider it to install a test server before production server.
you can use apache testing tools httperf http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/
to emulate your production server.